# How to add an address label as an input of files with just html code

Tags: html, input, label

There is this way in how to style an input in html using "Label" with
the following code, here is the example

```
<label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
</label>  -->

<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>

using only CSS style

  input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

I want to know if is possible to make the same with `<a>  </a>` instead of `<label></label>` and get the same results??? not using any code of javascript?
i tried to make it with

```
<a for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload </a>
<input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
```

but it does not work, i only want an address `<a></a>` as an input of file link with no javascript used.
anyhelp is appreciated

Thank you in advance

Omar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is No, why?
Well, you already know that the connection between the **label** tag and **input** tag is the **for** attribute, but that attribute is not a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes), so one must check if an **a** tag has it, and the bad new is that it doesn't have it, check [this table](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_a.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If you try to upload files, you need to add the **enctype** attribute in the **form** element that contains all your code. Because if you see the [documentation](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) of  element, you can't see any related with uploading files, just attributes that establish a relation between the linked site and your webpage.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    input[type="file"] {
        display: none;
    }
    .custom-file-upload {
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 6px 12px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="/action.php" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
        </label>  -->
        <input id="file-upload" type="file"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, thank you very much for your answer, but my question is? instead of label <label></label> which is indide form,  how to use the input form with <a></a>?, i was not able to make it work, is it possible to do this?

Comment: I understand, but I think you can't, check my second answer.